# Replacing first word of every line in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

My html view displays contents of an `.htgroup` file on screen, for example:

```
download: user1 user2 user3
movies: test test2 user1 user2 user3
```

I want to encapsulate the group names (`download` and `movies`) in `<strong>` tags, so that they appear bold in the browser. How can I do this in PHP5? I'm sure there is an elegant way to do this with a function like [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), but I'm very bad at regex.

Line separator is `\n`.

Comment: That looks like a premade string. Instead of replacing the end result, find, where the string is made and make the adjustments there.

Comment: @DainisAbols you really suggest pollution raw data with presentation markup?!

Comment: @Dainis Abols as stated in the first line of the question, it contains the contents of a `.htgroup` file.

Comment: @MikeBrant Nothing, what I would do is get the `strpos()` of the `:` characters, insert `</strong>` before them (or just str_replace), then add `<strong>` to index `0`, and then add `<strong>` again after every linebreak. I'm interested in some elegant solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can cheat and do it with `str_replace` in this case, like `$line = "<strong>".str_replace(":", ":</strong>", $line);`, but the non-messy and reliable way is to use regex.

Comment: +1 `str_replace` or `explode` seem better solutions than a regex here.

Comment: Note that this does not consider what will happen if there is a second colon on the line (my answer does) . Probably wouldn't make any difference and there probably wouldn't be another colon anyway, but just sayin'

Comment: @ExplosionPills exactly, it was just an example to start off.

Answer (score 2):

You gave no specifics about how the text is formatted, so maybe this?

```
$htgroup = preg_replace('/^.*?:/m', '<strong>\0</strong>', $htgroup);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that every row is separated by a `\n`, an elegant regex solution would be:

```
$str = "download: user1 user2 user3\n".
"movies: test test2 user1 user2 user3";

$rows = explode( "\n", $str );
foreach( $rows as $r ){
    echo preg_replace('/^([^ ]*):/', '<strong>$1</strong>:', $r);
}
```

Then probably you'd like to add a line break after every row, if you want to use a html(-ish) layout. But I leave to you the presentation part.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is need for regex.  Something like this should easily do the trick

```
$lines = file('/path/to/.htgroup');

foreach($lines as $line) {
    echo '<strong>' . str_replace(':', ':</strong>', $line) . '<br />';
}
```

Note the addition of a line break to preserve the output on different lines in the browser.